# Avoid phone heating up in gps location tracking

Tags: cordova, galaxy, android-gps, warm-up

I am working in a cordova app with geolocation in html5 for Android devices, all is fine except because the Samsung devices are heating up when the app is getting and sending the geolocation.

Is there a way to control or avoid device warming in geolocation?

This is a part of the code I am using:

```
 function localizame() {
id_watch = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(coords, errores, {'enableHighAccuracy':true,'timeout':20000,'maximumAge':0});
}

function coords(position) {
lat = position.coords.latitude;
lng = position.coords.longitude;
pres = position.coords.accuracy; // presición
vel = position.coords.speed;  //velocidad m/s
vel = parseInt(vel*3.6); 
dir = position.coords.heading; // azimuth
if (!pres || pres == 0) pres = 2000;
```

Comment: If you're willing to compromise on latency or accuracy, sure. Operating off of cell-tower triangulation is significantly easier on the hardware; and allowing the GPS to only be turned on sporadically, likewise. If you're asking for something with no tradeoffs, then you're in the realm of fantasy.